# How do you import Blueprint 2 in LESS through webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, less, blueprintjs

The [Blueprint docs](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v2/#blueprint.npm-installation) say to use this:

```
@import "~@blueprintjs/core";
```

However, if I try that, I get this error from webpack:

```
Can't resolve '@blueprintjs/core.less'
```

[Issue 123](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/123) deals with similar issues and a lot of people suggested using this:

```
@import "~@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css";
```

webpack doesn't like that either:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css'
```

Looking in the `dist/` directory, I can see that there's only a JS file in there:

```
$ ls node_modules/\@blueprintjs/core/dist/
core.bundle.js
```

After some trial and error, I found that this works:

```
@import "~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
```

But this doesn't seem right to me. Also, none of the icons are loaded via this method.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the Blueprint devs responded to my GitHub issue with some helpful info. You can see the full thread here: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/2057

In short, `@blueprintjs/icons` must be installed as well and another stylesheet has to be imported:

```
@import '~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css';
@import '~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css';
```